# Assigning form variable value to html element

Tags: html, coldfusion

I have a search bar. Entering text in it and clicking search takes you to another page which displays the search results.

Issue is, this search bar is visible at the top of every page in the application and is not a part of any particular page(including the search page).

As per the requirement, I am required to show the old search string in the search bar. Something like google.

Comment: You should use sessions variables --> http://www.school-for-champions.com/coldfusion/sessionvariable.htm

Comment: Session variables won't help because if I want to start a new search and go to some other random page, the old string will still be preserved.

Comment: As it's a search, your FORM method should be GET.  The search results will be in the URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the file that actually displays your search form you could add the following (assuming the form field name is 'search'

```
<cfparam name="form.search" default="" />
<input type="text" name="search" value="#HTMLEditFormat(form.search)#" ... />
```

Make sure the INPUT has CFOUTPUT tags around it as well.  Also, use HTMLEditFormat() when outputing input variables, otherwise you are opening yourself to injection attacks.

Comment: Also, please sanitize this variable before display it because this is a HUGE security risk. In general, it's always a bad idea to output variables directly to HTML. I think the very latest CF9 patch helps, but its better safe than sorry. We use OWASP's Anti-Sammy with great success.

Answer (score 0):

If you're posting the form then:

```
<input ... value='#form.FieldName#' />
```

If you're passing it through the url then:

```
<input ... value='#url.FieldName#' />
```

Use ifs or cfparams to your likening to control how it's displayed.